# Redirect a Windows thread's STDIN and STDOUT to named pipes?

Tags: windows, multithreading, stdout, named-pipes, io-redirection

I am implementing Lua functionality in [Ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/), which is my Google Summer of Code assignment. As a part of the project, I need to port the standard its input/output redirection mechanism to make it as compatible with the POSIX version as possible.

In the POSIX version, the process forked in one place and the child process had his standard input and standard output bound to POSIX pipes. Then, a piece of code that executed the script kicks in and all the printf's there get redirected to a relevant function in the parent process. How to emulate this behavior in Windows code?

What I need is a way to redirect the standard output and standard input of a thread to pipes created using `CreatePipe`. [Here](https://svn.nmap.org/!svn/bc/31014/nmap-exp/d33tah/ncat-lua/ncat/ncat_exec_win.c) is the current Ncat's Windows code and [here](https://svn.nmap.org/!svn/bc/31014/nmap-exp/d33tah/ncat-lua/ncat/ncat_posix.c) is the functionality I'm trying to accomplish (grep for NCAT_LUA) to find the relevant code). The project can be built on Windows - the instructions are [here](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html#inst-win-source). Feel free to experiment with it and sorry for not providing a smaller testcase.

I would be really grateful for any pointers to pieces of documentation to relevant functions/system calls, alternative approaches I could use, examples of code or links to source codes of projects which employ a solution to any similar problems.

Comment: Threads don't have independent standard input and output, but you could launch a child process instead.  See MSDN "Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The approach creates a problem of jumping back to the specific spot in the code and copying the program's state. Sounds pretty painful.

Comment: Do you actually need the entire program's state though?  There's no getting around the fact that anything using `fork()` has to be rearchitectured to run in Windows, whether to a subprocess or to a thread depends on the context.